# Xcode 5 develop code can run in IPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5 for developing and I want to test my build and I have iphone 4s. So is it possible to test my build in IPhone 4s?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There are two scenarios

1) if you installing the app using xcode 5 then your iPhone 4s should be running IOS 7, otherwise it won't install.
2) Installing app using itunes by making binary first and then installing it on iPhone. In this case you have to check your deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can read: [Run Your App on a Connected Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RunYourApp/RunYourApp.html)